# Convert Miles to Kilometers in a range given by the user and display them in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, onclick

I am required to write the code using three files, Javascript, HTML, and CSS. I am not sure what is the problem in my code, please help me find the error. The user is to write the range in two textareas and when a button is clicked convert all values starting from the first given number up to the second given number. This is what I have written so far:

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/converter.css"/>
    <title>Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/c2f.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h2>
<form action="">
    <p>
       <textarea rows="1" name="Input1" id="Input1" cols="10"></textarea>
        <textarea rows="1" name="Input2" id="Input2" cols="10"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Convert" name="B3" onclick="conversionTable()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="B2">
    </p>
</form>
<div id="conversion">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function conversionTable(tagId, from, to)
{
    var first = document.getElementById("Input1");
    var second = document.getElementById("Input2");
    from =first;
    to = second;
    var conv = document.getElementById(tagId);
    var tab = document.createElement("table");
    var bod = document.createElement("tbody");
    var thed = document.createElement("thead");
    tab.appendChild(thed);
    tab.appendChild(bod);
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    thed.appendChild(tr);
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    tr.appendChild(th);
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Miles"));
    th = document.createElement("th");
    tr.appendChild(th);
    th.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Kilometers"));
    conv.appendChild(tab);



    for(var i=from; i<=to; i++){
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
        if (i%2==0)
            tr.setAttribute("class", "even");
        else
            tr.setAttribute("class", "odd");
        bod.appendChild(tr);
        td = document.createElement("td");
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
        td = document.createElement("td");
        tr.appendChild(td);
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(c2f(i)));
    }
    function c2f(c) {return Math.round((c * 1.6093)*10)/10}
}
```

CSS code:

```
h2{text-align:center; color:blue; background: #EFEFEF}
body{margin: 4em; width: 400px}
table{margin: 2em; padding: 1em;}
th{background: #EFEFFF}
tr.even {background: #B8B8B8}
tr.odd {background: #E0FFFF}
```

So again, I am trying to pass the two variables (first and second) into my conversionTable() function.

Comment: Yes, but I have already edited that, no idea why it did not do it.

Comment: the first wrong I can see in your code, it's your calling the function conversionTable(tagId, from, to) in the form without their parameters

Comment: What it's suppose to be tagId, from, to??

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, I've tried calling it with parameters but didn't work as well, so I left it empty for now.

Comment: Let me ask you...you have to do this with pure javascript or can you use jquery?

Comment: Well first I created a conversion table without a user input, so I used these three parameters to pass into the conversionTable() function , so if you change the html tag '<body>' to '<body onload='conversionTable('conversion',1,30)'>' It'll sort the list for you in both units.

Comment: The only allowed programming languages are HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: inline javascript is discouraged it's bad practice, http://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/4fb3efd84db52c0003016f00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LwDKf/)

**Changes to your html:**

```
<input type="button" value="Convert" name="B3" onclick="conversionTable('conversion')" />
```

**Changes to your js:**

```
from = parseInt(first.value);
to = parseInt(second.value);
```

and thats it. It should work to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, that worked. Hopefully I will be able to sort out the validations now.

Comment: Emilio, you have to put from low to high in the boxes from left to right, if you put 50 40 it wont work, but if you put 40 50 it will.

Comment: Since the OP is not doing addition, there is no need for parseInt (and there was no requirement for integers in the OP).

Comment: in the for loop he's doing `for(var i=from; i<=to; i++){`

Answer (score 1):

An exmaple of using plain javascript to build the conversion table:

```
<form action="">
  <p>
    <textarea rows="1" name="Input1" cols="10"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="1" name="Input2" cols="10"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Convert" name="B3" onclick="buildConversionTable(this);">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="B2">
  </p>
</form>

<div id="conversion"></div>

<script>

// Convert miles to kilometres, round to 2 places
function m2k(c) {
  return (c * 1.6093).toFixed(2);  // returns a string
}

// Return a new element with provided tag name and properties
function newElement(tagName,props) {
  var el = document.createElement(tagName);
  if (props) {
    for (var prop in props) {
      if (props.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        el[prop] = props[prop];
      }
    }
  }
  return el;
}

// Return a new text node with text as content
function newText(text) {
  return document.createTextNode(text);
}

// Create the conversion table
function buildConversionTable(button) {
  var form = button.form;
  var from = form.Input1.value;
  var to   = form.Input2.value;

  // Use a temporary element to build the tabel from HTML
  var d = document.createElement('div');
  d.innerHTML = '<table><thead><tr><th>Miles<th>Kilometres</thead></table>';
  var table = d.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

  // Tables always have at least one tbody, no need for tags in the HTML
  var tbody = table.tBodies[0]

  // Use the convenience of appendChild returning the appended element
  for (var i=from, row, cell; i<=to; i++) {
    row = tbody.appendChild(newElement('tr',{className: i%2? 'odd':'even'}));
    cell = row.appendChild(newElement('td'));
    cell.appendChild(newText(i));
    cell = row.appendChild(newElement('td'));
    cell.appendChild(newText(m2k(i)));
  }

  // Add the table to the document  
  document.getElementById('conversion').appendChild(table);
}

</script>
```

Oh, forgot about the DOM table methods. The for loop adding the rows can be:

```
  for (var i=from, row, cell; i<=to; i++) {
    row = tbody.insertRow(-1);
    row.insertCell(-1);
    row.insertCell(-1);
    row.className = i%2? 'odd':'even';
    row.cells[0].innerHTML = i;
    row.cells[1].innerHTML = m2k(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using jQuery to solve this problem.  To include jquery in your project change your html to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/converter.css"/>
    <title>Celsius to Fahrenheit Converter</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../js/c2f.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <!-- Here is your jquery code includer -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h2>

<form action="">
    <p>
        <textarea rows="1" name="Input1" id="Input1" cols="10"></textarea>
        <textarea rows="1" name="Input2" id="Input2" cols="10"></textarea>
        <input type="button" value="Convert" id="convert" name="B3" />
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="B2" />
    </p>
</form>
<div id="conversion"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using jQuery you can add the click handler to the convert button and in there calculate the from and to and call the conversionTable function.  I have revised the conversionTable function to do what you want in much less code using jQuery.

```
$("#convert").click(function () {
    var from = parseInt($("#Input1").val());
    var to = parseInt($("#Input2").val());
    conversionTable($("#conversion"), from, to);
});

function conversionTable(tag, from, to) {
    //Generate the table with the thead of miles and kilometers
    var table = $("<table><thead>" +
        "<tr><th>Miles</th><th>Kilometers</th></tr>" +
        "</thead><tbody></tbody></table>");
    //set the tags innerHtml to the table
    tag.html(table);

    for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        var miles = i;
        var kilometers = c2f(i);
        //Create a tr with the found miles and kilometers
        var tr = $("<tr><td>" + miles + "</td><td>" + kilometers + "</td></tr>");
        //Add the tr to the tables tbody
        table.find("tbody").append(tr);
    }
    //Find all of the even and odd tr's and give them the appropriate class
    table.find("tr:even").addClass("even");
    table.find("tr:odd").addClass("odd");

    function c2f(c) {
        return Math.round((c * 1.6093) * 10) / 10;
    }
}
```

Your css would stay the same as previously posted.  You can find a working jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/FsV3j/.

Comment: Appreciate it, but as I commented before, this is an assignment, I'm am not allowed to use **Jquery**, but it looks way simpler than my current code to be honest.

Comment: I would not recommend jQuery to anyone learning javascript. @KhalifaBader—your code can be very much cleaner in plain javascript too, you don't need jQuery for that.